# Can different chat rooms be pinned to the side bar?

Tags: support, chat

I'm generally interested in making more use of chat. Before I raise a meta questions about how might that be achieved I'd just like to ask a technical question. If we were to create a new/different chat room - could this be pinned to the front page side bar? Is it the moderators who can do this? Someone else maybe?

As an aside I've just noticed that our chat room has disappeared from the front page. Not a major issue but obviously chat rooms can change locations on the site. Unless I've just got chat room blindness and it is still there.

Comment: I don't think we have much control over the site layout until we graduate beta (if we do). Even then, I imagine we only get to make cosmetic changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any chat room associated with Buddhism on chat.stackexchange.com will show up in that little sidebar widget as long as it's not a private room. Make as many rooms as you like! The widget shows 2 rooms at a time and chooses the most recently active rooms to show.